# spring class variable remains although i call the api twice

Tags: spring, spring-boot

i expected if i call the api twice , then the class variables will be initialized
but it's not. i want to know why.

**what did i do**

- /login?name=Jay
- /myName => Jay returned

**what i expected**

- /login?name=Jay
- /myName => null returned

here is my source code

```
package com.example.study;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.util.HashMap;

@RestController
public class LoginController {

    // login?name=Jay
    HashMap<String, String> sessionMap = new HashMap<>();

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login(HttpSession session, @RequestParam String name){
        sessionMap.put(session.getId(), name);

        return "saved";
    }

    @GetMapping("/myName")
    public String myName(HttpSession session){
        String myName = sessionMap.get(session.getId());

        return myName;
    }
}
```

Comment: i guess your session id might be different for every request

Comment: Why would you expect `null`? You store it based on the session id as long as yu keep the session it will be there.

Comment: @M.Deinum i expected null because `HashMap<String, String> sessionMap = new HashMap<>();` will run whenever i call the api.

Comment: No it won't. The controller is a singleton, so it will only be created once.